# Use PDFBox to display content of a PDF file in Android

Tags: android, pdf, pdfbox

how to use apache pdfbox port by  tom rush in android to display the content of a PDF file as it is ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [dependencies page](http://pdfbox.apache.org/dependencies.html) of PDFBox documentation.

Here is a quote from the document:

> The three PDFBox components are named pdfbox, fontbox and jempbox. The Maven groupId of all PDFBox components is org.apache.pdfbox.
>
> The fontbox and jempbox components are standalone libraries for handling font information and XMP metadata. These components have no external dependencies and can be used simply by adding the respective jar files to the classpath of your application.
>
> The main PDFBox component, pdfbox, has hard dependencies on the fontbox and jempbox components and the commons-logging library.

As it says, there are 2 dependencies, jempbox and fontbox (they are also open-source). Both depend on commons-logging, which can somehow be set to not require log4j, but use standard Java logging API. I don't know exactly if Android fully implements standard Java logging API.

Anyway, if you are using Eclipse, there is no problem in setting source dependencies. Just create a Java project for each library source and set your Android project dependent on those Java projects in its Build Path. I have done this and it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks! i'll take a look. It seems that PDFBox lets you modify or create PDF files, but i still doesn´t know if can display pdf files in Android Apps.

Comment: I think you should try displaying different PDF documents on your PC first to be sure PDFBox works. I have a PDF with just English text on 3 pages, which didn't look normal when I tried PDFBox today. Fonts were messed up and scrolling lagged very much. I would consider some other alternatives besides PDFBox, but I can't help you with this as I don't know any good examples.

Comment: Thanks! I haven´t considered that. I'm starting to think that with "PDFBox" you have to construct the PDF yourself. With "PDFBox" you can construct PDF and take the elements of an existing PDF, but display an existing PDF is not one of its assets. I'm 99% sure of this.

Comment: @Victor: I tried all of the above steps which you had mentioned in order to integrate the PDFBox component into my Android project. Unfortunately even after all this effort, the application still crashes with the same error as seen in my previous attempts. In my previous attempts I used to just integrate the PDFBox jar instead of the sources and stuff. ERROR 04-17 11:36:51.785: I/dalvikvm(1213): Failed resolving Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument; interface 509 'Ljava/awt/print/Pageable;'
04-17 11:36:51.785: W/dalvikvm(1213): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;' failed

Comment: @Crisloks: I am 100% sure that PDFBox can be used to display existing PDF documents, but the only issue is that of compatibility with the Android platform. On a regular desktop using J2SE environment there are many projects demonstrating this but I'm looking for something similar on Android,unfortunately couldn't find anything so far.

Comment: @Victor: are you sure about what you claimed in the answer? I've tried it and it failed miserably. What is the exact version of PdfBox software which you'd used?